# Qt5 Linker Error: version `Qt_5' not found

Tags: qt, qt5

## 1 The Problem

I am attempting to build the open-source [motorcar](https://github.com/evil0sheep/motorcar) project from scratch on an Arch Linux machine.  Motorcar is a linux VR window manager to be used with the Oculus Rift D2K headset in conjunction with Razer Hydra controllers. You don't need these items to actually compile this project though.

**The problem:** I cannot get motorcar to compile on my machine (Arch Linux). I am suffering from a Qt5 linking error (explained below).

## 2 Motorcar Prerequisites & Build Targets

As the [README](https://github.com/evil0sheep/motorcar) indicates, the following prerequisites are needed in order to build motorcar:

1. Mesa, compiled with EGL and Desktop OpenGL support.
2. Cairo, compiled with EGL and Desktop OpenGL support.
3. QtWayland 5.5 (which requires Qt5.5).
4. Wayland (a linux window manager protocol).

Furthermore, the motorcar project is divided up into the following actual build targets:

1. `libmotorcar-compositor`: this is the actual motorcar library used to support the build targets after this one.
2. `simple-compositor`: this is a simple Wayland compositor which you can launch from the console. Once it's launched (on your screen, not in a VR headset), you can launch 3D window programs within it.
3. `rift-hydra-compositor`: this is the same as the `simple-compositor`, except it is equipped with support for the Oculus Rift D2K headset and Razer Hydra controllers.
4. `motorcar-client-demo`: This is the **client** "window" which is meant to run in either `simple-compositor` or the `rift-hydra-compositor`. It's merely a rotating cube. Once you launch the `simple-compositor`, you should be able to alt-tab to a console and run `motorcar-client-demo` (which will launch the 3D cube within the running `simple-compositor`).

## 3 How I Attempted to Build the Motorcar Targets (And the Errors That I'm Getting)

My system: Arch Linux with nvidia graphics card (running `nvidia` drivers).

First note that the motorcar project provides a `build.sh` script. I've tried using it and it doesn't work on my system. Therefore, I compiled everything from source. Here is how I did it (leading to the eventual error).

### 3.1 How I Built Mesa

First I downloaded `mesa-13.0.2.tar.gz` from [mesa](ftp://ftp.freedesktop.org/pub/mesa/13.0.2/). After removing it from its tar, I ran:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=$WLD --enable-gles2 --disable-gallium-egl --with-egl-platforms=x11,wayland,drm --enable-gbm --enable-shared-glapi --with-gallium-drivers=r300,r600,swrast,nouveau --enable-glx-tls # what should $WLD be here? It might have been left blank.
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

### 3.2 How I Built Cairo

First I downloaded `LATEST-cairo-1.14.6` linked from [cairo's website](https://www.cairographics.org/releases). After removing it from its tar, I ran:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=$WLD --enable-xcb=yes --enable-gl=yes -enable-egl=yes # what should $WLD be here? It might have been left blank.
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

### 3.3 How I Built Wayland

I just used my package manager for this.

```
$ sudo pacman -S wayland
$ sudo pacman -S weston # in case this is relevant
```

### 3.4 How I Built qtwayland and qt5.5

Here I followed the instructions of motorcar's README:

```
$ cd ~
$ git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git qt5
$ cd qt5
$ git checkout 1497a398e34e18abb18f705b2294464840629ca1 # the Qt5 commit hash confirmed to work from the README
$ ./init-repository --no-webkit  --module-subset=qtbase,qtdeclarative,qtwayland # I removed qtjsbackend from the module-subset since it isn't strictly needed

$ cd qtbase
$ git checkout 7010da2e6274febf71db40a535ce1d0c4858f143 # the qtbase commit hash confirmed to work from the README
$ cd ../qtwayland
$ git checkout 3dc9cfdbd2771c28c770d432b99e571db43fe599 # the qtwayland commit hash confirmed to work from the README
$ cd ../
$ ./configure -prefix /opt/qt5  -debug -confirm-license -opensource -egl -opengl -no-xcb-xlib

$ cd qtwayland
$ git clean -fdx
$ ../qtbase/bin/qmake CONFIG+=wayland-compositor
$ cd ../
$ make -j4 # the -j4 flag speeds up make by a factor of 4; otherwise this build takes a LONG time
$ make install
```

### 3.5 How I built `libmotorcar-compositor`

```
$ cd ~
$ git clone https://github.com/evil0sheep/motorcar.git motorcar
$ /opt/qt5/bin/qmake
$ make
```

### 3.6 How I attempted and FAILED to build `simple-compositor`

```
$ cd ~/motorcar/src/examples/compositors/simple-compositor
$ make
g++  main.cpp  -std=c++11  -I../../../../src/compositor -I../../../../src/protocol -I../../../../src/device -L../../../../lib -lmotorcar-compositor  -o simple-compositor 
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QGuiApplication::primaryScreen()@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QSurfaceFormat::setDepthBufferSize(int)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWaylandCompositor::QWaylandCompositor(char const*, QFlags<QWaylandCompositor::ExtensionFlag>)'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QTimer::start(int)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QMatrix4x4::translate(float, float)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QOpenGLContext::defaultFramebufferObject() const@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QGuiApplication::exec()@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QSurfaceFormat::setStencilBufferSize(int)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QSurfaceFormat::~QSurfaceFormat()@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `qFlagLocation(char const*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QObject::childEvent(QChildEvent*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QMetaObject::Connection::~Connection()@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QObject::staticMetaObject@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWindow::metaObject() const@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWindow::create()@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWindow::focusObject() const@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWindow::setSurfaceType(QSurface::SurfaceType)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWindow::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWindow::accessibleRoot() const@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QOpenGLTextureCache::QOpenGLTextureCache(QOpenGLContext*)@Qt_5_PRIVATE_API'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QSurfaceFormat::QSurfaceFormat(QSurfaceFormat const&)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWindow::focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to QWindow::format() const@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QOpenGLShaderProgram::addShaderFromSourceCode(QFlags<QOpenGLShader::ShaderTypeBit>, char const*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QPixmap::fromImage(QImage const&, QFlags<Qt::ImageConversionFlag>)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QOpenGLTexture::QOpenGLTexture(QImage const&, QOpenGLTexture::MipMapGeneration)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWindow::qt_metacast(char const*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QScreen::geometry() const@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QObject::~QObject()@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QOpenGLShaderProgram::QOpenGLShaderProgram(QObject*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWindow::tabletEvent(QTabletEvent*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QObject::timerEvent(QTimerEvent*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWindow::showEvent(QShowEvent*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWindow::nativeEvent(QByteArray const&, void*, long*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWindow::setGeometry(QRect const&)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QMatrix4x4::scale(float, float)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QSurfaceFormat::setSwapInterval(int)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QObject::installEventFilter(QObject*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QOpenGLShaderProgram::release()@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWaylandCompositor::createOutput(QWindow*, QString const&, QString const&)'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QListData::dispose(QListData::Data*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QOpenGLContext::QOpenGLContext(QObject*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QOpenGLContext::create()@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QImage::height() const@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QTimer::~QTimer()@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch()@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QObject::eventFilter(QObject*, QEvent*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QCoreApplication::self@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QGuiApplication::screens()@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWindow::hideEvent(QHideEvent*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QObject::disconnectNotify(QMetaMethod const&)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QCursor::~QCursor()@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QCursor::QCursor(QPixmap const&, int, int)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QOpenGLTexture::textureId() const@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QImage::~QImage()@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QObject::connect(QObject const*, char const*, QObject const*, char const*, Qt::ConnectionType)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QObject::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QOpenGLContext::functions() const@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QObjectData::dynamicMetaObject() const@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QOpenGLContext::setFormat(QSurfaceFormat const&)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWaylandCompositor::openUrl(QWaylandClient*, QUrl const&)'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QScreen::refreshRate() const@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QGuiApplication::changeOverrideCursor(QCursor const&)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QObject::qt_metacast(char const*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QOpenGLShaderProgram::setUniformValue(int, QMatrix4x4 const&)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWindow::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QImage::QImage()@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWindow::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWindow::event(QEvent*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWindow::isExposed() const@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QImage::convertToFormat_helper(QImage::Format, QFlags<Qt::ImageConversionFlag>) const@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWindow::surfaceHandle() const@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWindow::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QListData::detach(int)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWindow::moveEvent(QMoveEvent*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QObject::sender() const@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `typeinfo for QWindow@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QString::fromAscii_helper(char const*, int)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QObject::event(QEvent*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWindow::QWindow(QScreen*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QOpenGLTexture::~QOpenGLTexture()@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to QWindow::surfaceType() const@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QPixmap::~QPixmap()@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QOpenGLShaderProgram::bind()@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QImage::width() const@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QGuiApplication::queryKeyboardModifiers()@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWindow::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWindow::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to QWindow::surfaceHandle() const@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QMetaObject::cast(QObject*) const@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QOpenGLContext::makeCurrent(QSurface*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWindow::exposeEvent(QExposeEvent*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWindow::~QWindow()@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QOpenGLShaderProgram::attributeLocation(char const*) const@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QImage::constBits() const@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QArrayData::deallocate(QArrayData*, unsigned long, unsigned long)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QGuiApplication::setOverrideCursor(QCursor const&)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWindow::format() const@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `qt_assert(char const*, char const*, int)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation(char const*) const@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWindow::showFullScreen()@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QOpenGLContext::currentContext()@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QSurfaceFormat::QSurfaceFormat()@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWindow::surfaceType() const@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QTimer::QTimer(QObject*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWindow::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWindow::geometry() const@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QWindow::setFormat(QSurfaceFormat const&)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QObject::connectNotify(QMetaMethod const&)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QOpenGLContext::swapBuffers(QSurface*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QObject::customEvent(QEvent*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QGuiApplication::QGuiApplication(int&, char**, int)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `QObject::QObject(QObject*)@Qt_5'
../../../../lib/libmotorcar-compositor.so: undefined reference to `typeinfo for QObject@Qt_5'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:14: compositor] Error 1
```

### 3.7 How I found the Qt5 linking error associated with `libmotorcar-compositor.so`

The above output led me to the discovery that there is an internal linking error associated with the `libmotorcar-compositor` library, as evidenced by the following (note the first three lines of the error):

```
$ cd ~/motorcar/lib
$ ls
libmotorcar-compositor.so  libmotorcar-compositor.so.1  libmotorcar-compositor.so.1.0  libmotorcar-compositor.so.1.0.0
$ ldd libmotorcar-compositor.so
./libmotorcar-compositor.so: /opt/qt5/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by ./libmotorcar-compositor.so)
./libmotorcar-compositor.so: /opt/qt5/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: version `Qt_5_PRIVATE_API' not found (required by ./libmotorcar-compositor.so)
./libmotorcar-compositor.so: /opt/qt5/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by ./libmotorcar-compositor.so)
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcb60c9000)
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /opt/qt5/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007f6084efa000)
    libQt5Compositor.so.5 => /opt/qt5/lib/libQt5Compositor.so.5 (0x00007f6084e1a000)
    libQt5Quick.so.5 => /opt/qt5/lib/libQt5Quick.so.5 (0x00007f60848f2000)
    libQt5Qml.so.5 => /opt/qt5/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5 (0x00007f60842dc000)
    libQt5Network.so.5 => /opt/qt5/lib/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x00007f6084133000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /opt/qt5/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007f6083a84000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /opt/qt5/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f60834c6000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f608322a000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f608300d000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f6082c85000)
    libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f6082981000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f608276a000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f60823ca000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f6082178000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f6081e65000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f6081c53000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f6081914000)
    libwayland-server.so.0 => /usr/lib/libwayland-server.so.0 (0x00007f6081701000)
    libxkbcommon.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxkbcommon.so.0 (0x00007f60814bf000)
    librt.so.1 => /usr/lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007f60812b7000)
    libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0x00007f60810a1000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f6080e6b000)
    libicui18n.so.57 => /usr/lib/libicui18n.so.57 (0x00007f60809f1000)
    libicuuc.so.57 => /usr/lib/libicuuc.so.57 (0x00007f6080647000)
    libicudata.so.57 => /usr/lib/libicudata.so.57 (0x00007f607ebcb000)
    libpcre16.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpcre16.so.0 (0x00007f607e962000)
    libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f607e75e000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f607e55c000)
    /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00005591851f1000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /usr/lib/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f607e332000)
    libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0x00007f607e12d000)
    libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-present.so.0 (0x00007f607df2a000)
    libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00007f607dd23000)
    libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib/libxshmfence.so.1 (0x00007f607db20000)
    libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/libglapi.so.0 (0x00007f607d8f1000)
    libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f607d6ee000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f607d4e6000)
    libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007f607d2e4000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f607d0bb000)
    libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007f607ce9f000)
    libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x00007f607cc9a000)
    libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007f607ca94000)
    libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007f607c882000)
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f607c679000)
    libpcre.so.1 => /usr/lib/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007f607c406000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f607c202000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f607bffc000)
```

Comment: On what operating system? How did you install Qt? Can't you use binary packages (e.g. most Linux distributions are packaging Qt5)? Wht do you need to compile from source Qt (and if you do, be sure to pick the latest one).

Comment: Arch Linux. I have been compiling Qt5 from source with EGL support. Because I need EGL support I can't just use the standard binary packages from my repo.

Comment: You should edit and improve your question, not comment it. I suspect that you made some mistake during Qt installation. Did you run `ldconfig`?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add Qt's `bin` directory to `PATH` and `lib` directory to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
export PATH=/opt/qt5/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/qt5/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I believe you may have linked your `shared-object.so` library explicitly against `/opt/qt5/lib/libQt5Core.so`, but as it in turn depends on other Qt libraries and cannot find them, you have an error. Adjustments above might resolve the issue.

See also:

- [What is the difference between PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44990/what-is-the-difference-between-path-and-ld-library-path)
- [Where is LD_LIBRARY_PATH? how do I set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168340/where-is-ld-library-path-how-do-i-set-the-ld-library-path-env-variable)
- [man ld.so(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html)

Comment: In principle, should I have to rebuild the project in order to try this (I have to rebuild the project from scratch regardless, I'm just curious)?

Comment: No, just put it into terminal and try to rerun your program. Of course, make sure that Qt executables are physically present in `/opt/qt5/bin` and Qt libraries are in `/opt/qt5/lib`. If it works, you may want to append these two lines to your `.bashrc` (or rc-file for whatever shell you are using) to load these at every session

Comment: Ok. The project is re-compiling (it takes about an hour). I'll report back on the results here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I altered the `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variables per your recommendation and received the same errors. Thanks for your suggestion but it didn't work :(

Comment: The next hypothesis then would be that the build system of your project is broken. Can you reproduce the problem with a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) created from scratch? (in this case you should include a minimal example of the build to your question).

Comment: Yes. I'm substantially re-writing my question with a detailed description of my actual build process (instead of the generalized one above which isn't specific enough).

Comment: if you can help me resolve this particularly thorny error, I'll throw in more bounty than the +50 it's currently worth.