# Can't run Qt apps: version `Qt_5' not found

Tags: qt, qt5, qmake

I run Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. 
My problem is that I am not able to run a Qt5 app, which I can compile.

This is what I get when I try to run it:

```
/home/user/Desktop/sconfig/dist/Release/GNU-Linux/SCongif: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5OpenGL.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by /home/user/Desktop/sconfig/dist/Release/GNU-Linux/SCongif)
/home/user/Desktop/sconfig/dist/Release/GNU-Linux/SCongif: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by /home/user/Desktop/sconfig/dist/Release/GNU-Linux/SCongif)
/home/user/Desktop/sconfig/dist/Release/GNU-Linux/SCongif: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.6' not found (required by /home/user/Desktop/sconfig/dist/Release/GNU-Linux/SCongif)
/home/user/Desktop/sconfig/dist/Release/GNU-Linux/SCongif: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by /home/user/Desktop/sconfig/dist/Release/GNU-Linux/SCongif)
/home/user/Desktop/sconfig/dist/Release/GNU-Linux/SCongif: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by /home/user/Desktop/sconfig/dist/Release/GNU-Linux/SCongif)
```

I then removed Qt5 and purged all the remnants. Then I installed again Qt5.

```
user@user-P64V7:~$ which qmake
/home/user/Qt5.8.0/5.8/gcc_64/bin/qmake
user@user-P64V7:~$ qmake --version
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.8.0 in /home/user/Qt5.8.0/5.8/gcc_64/lib
user@user-P64V7:~$ echo $PATH
/home/user/Qt5.8.0/5.8/gcc_64/bin:/home/user/bin:/home/user/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

It could also be worth noting that I use Netbeans 8.2 and the QMake command is

```
/home/user/Qt5.8.0/5.8/gcc_64/bin/qmake
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you read [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40945442/qt5-linker-error-version-qt-5-not-found?rq=1)?

Comment: Yes, I went through all of the threads I could find. My problem is not compilation, but execution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I figured out an answer according to these two previous questions:

- [Error on execution -version `Qt_5' not found required by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36128645/error-on-execution-version-qt-5-not-found-required-by)
- [How to set the environmental variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428910/how-to-set-the-environmental-variable-ld-library-path-in-linux)

To summarize, to add the libraries the right way, one should add a custom `.conf` file to the folder `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` containing all the absolute paths to library folders and then run `sudo ldconfig`. :)

Comment: Adding stuff in user home directory to global /etc/ld.so.conf.d is a bit dubious or at least ugly (for some definition of ugly)... I suppose it's fine on a personal workstation, but I'd rather add it to user-specific LD_LIBRARY_PATH, which is under the control of the user without root access.

Comment: Still, +1 for providing answer to your own unanswered question after figuring it out, which I always find commendable.

Comment: Actually, this is what I found among the answers from the second question:
_Since Ubuntu 9.04 Jaunty Jackalope, LD_LIBRARY_PATH cannot be set in $HOME/.profile, /etc/profile, nor /etc/environment files. You must use /etc/ld.so.conf.d/.conf configuration files._

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. I generally set LD_LIBRARY_PATH in `~/.bashrc`, it works for the applications I need it for.

Answer (score 0):

cpu: armv8
os: Linux kylin.5.desktop-generic 
upgrade from 5.6 to 5.9

Similar situations will appear after the program is released.

solution:

1. copy `/usr/local/Qt-5.9.2` to `/usr/local/` in target pc.
2. `qtchooser -install qt5.9 /usr/local/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/bin/qmake`
3. `sudo bash -c "echo export QT_SELECT=qt5.9 >> /etc/profile"`
4. `sudo ldconfig -v`